# Use DISTINCT as filter when calculating SUM

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax, distinct-values

**Software:** MS Excel 2016

Here is a table

[image]

Given, there will alway be same number of triggers for a particular ID. But I don't want to count those triggers multiple times.

I tried the following DAX. My expected answer is **72**, but I get **143** instead. How to fix?

```
Distinct_Matches:=CALCULATE(sum(Incidents[Triggers]),DISTINCT(Incidents[Incident_ID]))
```

Comment: Will the triggers always be the same number for the same ID?

Comment: There he goes again :P

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes, the triggers and ID have 1:1 relationship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B7/COUNTIF(A2:A7,A2:A7))
```

Here is the formula with structured references:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Incidents[Triggers]/COUNTIFS(Incidents[Incident_ID],Incidents[Incident_ID]))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The below would work, assuming that Incident_ID's trigger value is the same across the ID Number.

```
Measure 1:=SUMX( DISTINCT(Table1[Incident_ID]), CALCULATE(AVERAGE(Table1[Triggers])))
```

Table1 just being the name I used as part of the quick test.

The idea being that the sumx would iterate though every unique Incident_ID and sum the result of the calculate statement.  The calculate statement is using average, since it will return the unique value.  E.g. `Average(41+41) = 41`.  You could also use `MIN` or `MAX` as well.